# Installing a Go tool from github and facing installation errors

Tags: go, websecurity

I want to install this tool from github : https://github.com/ethicalhackingplayground/ssrf-tool

I am using the cmd :  `go install github.com/ethicalhackingplayground/ssrf-tool@latest`

Output :

```
go: finding module for package github.com/projectdiscovery/gologger
go: finding module for package github.com/briandowns/spinner
go: finding module for package github.com/logrusorgru/aurora
go: found github.com/briandowns/spinner in github.com/briandowns/spinner v1.18.1
go: found github.com/logrusorgru/aurora in github.com/logrusorgru/aurora v2.0.3+incompatible
go: found github.com/projectdiscovery/gologger in github.com/projectdiscovery/gologger v1.1.4
# github.com/ethicalhackingplayground/ssrf-tool
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\ethicalhackingplayground\ssrf-tool@v0.0.0-20200901082948-7f3cffc3c7bb\ssrftool.go:34:2: undefined: gologger.Printf
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\ethicalhackingplayground\ssrf-tool@v0.0.0-20200901082948-7f3cffc3c7bb\ssrftool.go:35:2: undefined: gologger.Infof
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\ethicalhackingplayground\ssrf-tool@v0.0.0-20200901082948-7f3cffc3c7bb\ssrftool.go:36:2: undefined: gologger.Infof
```

I am super new to golang, go installation is fine in my system because other tools from github are working fine.
If some changes are required in the code of this tool, please suggest so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sources created without go module support and an old version of `gologger`, here is a workaround:

1. Clone repository `git clone git@github.com:ethicalhackingplayground/ssrf-tool.git`
2. `cd ssrf-tool` create `go.mod` file with content:

```golang
module github.com/ethicalhackingplayground/ssrf-tool

go 1.17

require (
    github.com/briandowns/spinner v1.18.1
    github.com/logrusorgru/aurora v2.0.3+incompatible
    github.com/projectdiscovery/gologger v1.0.1
)

require (
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/fatih/color v1.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.8 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190222072716-a9d3bda3a223 // indirect
)
```

3. download deps `go mod download`
4. Build executable `go build .`
5. `./ssrf-tool --help`

Profit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the repo](https://github.com/R0X4R/ssrf-tool) with the problem fixed.

```sh
go install github.com/R0X4R/ssrf-tool@latest
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/R0X4R/ssrf-tool.git
cd ssrf-tool
go build ssrftool.go && mv ssrftool /usr/bin/
```